# calculate rowSum in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, dataframe, dplyr, sparklyr

Hi I have a a following spark dataframe. I want to sum across rows. I couldn't find any equivalent function of row sum in sparklyr. I tried the following query but it sums the column values.

```
trans1M_20 %>% 
        dplyr::select(trans1M_20_clicks) %>%
        dplyr::select(Small_SubChannel_Clicks_names) %>%
        dplyr::summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

Note that Alma_1 is the Small_Subchannel_Clicks_names.

Alma_1

```
<dbl>

0               
0               
0               
0               
0               
0               
0               
0               
0               
0
```

I am trying to aggregate multiple columns into one single column and summing the rows. `Small_SubChannel_Clicks_names` can contain n number of column names. I want to do something like:

```
rowSums(trans1M_20[, Small_SubChannel_Clicks_names,drop=F]) –
```

Answer (score 3):

As long as number of columns is low you can just generate and evaluate the  expression:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

df <- copy_to(sc, data.frame(x=c(1, 3), y=c(2, 4)))

columns_to_sum <- colnames(df)

df %>% transmute(total = !!parse_expr(paste(columns_to_sum, collapse = " + ")))
```

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 1]
# Database: spark_connection
  total
  <dbl>
1     3
2     7
```

Unfortunately this won't work with larger number of columns. For workarounds see [Efficiently calculate row totals of a wide spark DF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47818851/6910411).

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do what you want by means of using the `DBI` package, which allows you to send SQL queries to your Spark table. It's not a `dplyr` solution, but it might be useful anyway until someone else comes with a more "dply-ish" solution.

You have to manually include your column names in your query. For instance, if you wanted to get the sum of the columns "trans1M_20_clicks" and "Small_SubChannel_Clicks_names", you could do something like this:

```
resSparkSQL <- DBI::dbSendQuery(sc, "SELECT trans1M_20_clicks + Small_SubChannel_Clicks_names as Total FROM your_table_name_in_spark")
```

The result is a [DBISparkResultObject](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sparklyr/versions/0.6.0/topics/DBISparkResult-class), although you could get the result column into R as a `data.frame`:

```
resSparkSQL <- DBI::dbGetQuery(sc, "SELECT trans1M_20_clicks + Small_SubChannel_Clicks_names as Total FROM your_table_name_in_spark")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Small_SubChannel_Clicks_names can contain any number of columns"? When you use `dplyr::select(Small_SubChannel_Clicks_names)`, you are selecting just that column.

Comment: Small_SubChannel_Click_names contains names of multiple column so when I used this in select statement so I get a subset of these columns no I want to merge them into one single column.

Comment: No need for manual thing - just `paste("SELECT", paste(cols, collapse=" + "), "as Total FROM your_table_name_in_spark")` or `glue::glue("SELECT {paste(cols, collapse=' + ')} as Total FROM your_table_name_in_spark")` where `cols` is a vector of names.